# Using recursion in java to find the next double in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Given an array, data[ ],  my goal is to find the number of elements followed by a double.
(If it was a simple for loop, it'd look something like this)

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i ++) {
        if(data[i]*2 == data[i+1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

My issue, however, is finding a certain section of the code recursively, as noted by the question marks. I'm having trouble determining how to compare a value found in the previous method call to the current method call.

```
public int allDoubles(int[] data) {
    int count = 0;
    //return the total doubles found
    return doubleFinder(data, 0, data.length, count);

}


private int doubleFinder(int data[], int low, int high, int count) {
    if (low == high) {
        return 0;
    } else  {   // low < high
        if( ?(previous value == current value)? ) {
            count++;
        }
        doubleFinder(data, low, high -1, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: could you please includes sample input and expected output?

Comment: an array of ints such as {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256} would return 8 and something like {1, 0, 0, -5, -10, 32, 64, 128, 2, 9, 18} would return 5

Comment: But what should `doubleFinder(new int[] {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256}, 3, 5, 7)` be? I'm guessing `9`?

Comment: Yes that sounds right

Comment: You seem to be trying to mix two things together. You either want a method `doubleFinder(int data[], int low, int high)` that returns the number of doubles between `low` and `high`, **or** you want a method `doubleFinder(int data[], int low, int high, int count)` that *adds* the value of `count` to the number of doubles between `low` and `high`. The statement `if (low == high) return 0;` only makes sense if you are doing it the first way, but the presence of `count` only makes sense if you are doing it the second way.

Comment: This sounds like one of those scrap and restart moments. Thanks for the starting point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the calculated result back up to the calling method. Since java is call-by-value, this won't work. Also you pass the wrong values to `doubleFinder` in `allDoubles`: You should use `(data, 0, data.length-1, count)` instead of `(data, 0, data.length, count)`.

Your method could be fixed like this:

```
private int doubleFinder(int data[], int low, int high, int count) {
    if (low == high) {
        return count;
    } else  {   // low < high
        if(data[high-1]*2 == data[high]) {
            count++;
        }
        // pass the count from the base case to calling method
        return doubleFinder(data, low, high -1, count);
    }
}
```

but you can even remove `count`:

```
private int doubleFinder(int data[], int low, int high) {
    if (low == high) {
        // just 1 value
        return 0;
    } else if (data[low]*2 == data[low+1]) {
        // 1 "double" found -> add 1
        return 1 + doubleFinder(data, low+1, high);
    } else {
        return doubleFinder(data, low+1, high);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of `doubleFinder()` which recursively compares `data[i] == 2*data[i-i]`, beginning with the highest index in the input array `data`.  It counts 1 for every double (not the type) found, and returns the total count of doubles for the input entered.

```
private int doubleFinder(int data[], int index) {
    if (index <= 0) {
        return 0; // reached last number in array 'data'
    } else {
        if (data[index] == 2*data[index-1])
            return doubleFinder(data, index-1) + 1;
        else {
            doubleFinder(data, index-1)
        }
    }
}
```